# display message based on time zone input

Tags: c#

I have an application that displays the time from a time zone for a specific area code, the time for that area code, and a message that will be displayed based on the time from 8 am to 8 pm. The problem I am having is making the application display the message for the time displayed based on the area code instead of the current time on my PC. I know that my code is incorrect because it uses
 `DateTime.Now` 
Instead of the time from my digital clock label which is chosen by the Time Zone of a specific area code.
Here is my code the problem is in the if statement where I parse the DateTime.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TimeZone
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void areaCodeDataBaseTableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.areaCodeDataBaseTableBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.areaCodeDataBaseDataSet);

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'areaCodeDataBaseDataSet.AreaCodeDataBaseTable' table. 
        //You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.areaCodeDataBaseTableTableAdapter.Fill(this.areaCodeDataBaseDataSet.AreaCodeDataBaseTable);

    }

    private void DigitalClock_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
        t.Interval = 1000;
        t.Enabled = true;
    }        

    public void t_Tick(Object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        DateTime start = DateTime.Parse("08:00 am");
        DateTime end = DateTime.Parse("08:00 pm").AddHours(10);

        if (time_ZoneLabel1.Text == "Eastern")
        {
            DigitalClock.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(19).ToLongTimeString();
            DigitalClock2.Text = "";
        }
        if (time_ZoneLabel1.Text == "Central")
        {
            DigitalClock.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(18).ToLongTimeString();
            DigitalClock2.Text = "";
        }
        if (time_ZoneLabel1.Text == "Mountain")
        {
            DigitalClock.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(17).ToLongTimeString();
            DigitalClock2.Text = "";
        }
        if (time_ZoneLabel1.Text == "Pacific")
        {
            DigitalClock.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(16).ToLongTimeString();
            DigitalClock2.Text = "";
        }
        if (time_ZoneLabel1.Text == "Atlantic")
        {
            DigitalClock.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(20).ToLongTimeString();
            DigitalClock2.Text = "";
        }
        if (time_ZoneLabel1.Text == "Hawaii-Aleutian")
        {
            DigitalClock.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(14).ToLongTimeString();
            DigitalClock2.Text = "";
        }
        if (time_ZoneLabel1.Text == "Eastern/Central")
        {
            DigitalClock.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(19).ToLongTimeString();
            DigitalClock2.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(18).ToLongTimeString();
        }
        if (time_ZoneLabel1.Text == "Central/Mountain")
        {
            DigitalClock.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(18).ToLongTimeString();
            DigitalClock2.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(17).ToLongTimeString();
        }
        if (time_ZoneLabel1.Text == "Mountain/Pacific")
        {
            DigitalClock.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(17).ToLongTimeString();
            DigitalClock2.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(16).ToLongTimeString();
        }
        if (time_ZoneLabel1.Text == "UTC+10")
        {
            DigitalClock.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(10).ToLongTimeString();
            DigitalClock2.Text = "";
        }
        if (time_ZoneLabel1.Text == "UTC-10")
        {
            DigitalClock.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(20).ToLongTimeString();
            DigitalClock2.Text = "";
        }
        if (time_ZoneLabel1.Text == "")
        {
            DigitalClock.Text = "";
            DigitalClock2.Text = "";                
        }
        if (DateTime.Parse(DigitalClock.Text) > start && (DateTime.Parse(DigitalClock.Text) < end))
        {
            warningLabel.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            warningLabel.Text = "OK To Call";
        }
        else
        {
            warningLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            warningLabel.Text = "Do Not Call";
        }
        if (DigitalClock.Text == "")
        {
            warningLabel.Text = "";
        }        
    }        

    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }               

}
} code here
```

Comment: You are using DateTime.UtcNow, and seem to adjust the time based on this, so what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing conversions in different places using different methods, which is kind of confusing.  Consider re-working your code so that you use the time zone to determine the offset, like this:

```
int HoursOffset = 0;
switch (time_ZoneLabel1)
{
    case "Eastern" :
        HoursOffset = 19;
        break;
    case "Central" :
        HoursOffset = 18;
        break;
    // etc, for all your timezones
}
```

Now, get the time at that location:

```
DateTime currentLocalTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(HoursOffset);
```

You can then set the digital clock text:

```
DigitalClock.Text = currentLocalTime.ToLongTimeString();
```

Now, to determine if you can call, you can compare the `Hour` value from the `currentLocalTime` against the start and end hours:

```
int startHour = 8;
int endHour = 20;

if (currentLocalTime.Hour >= startHour && currentLocalTime.Hour < endHour)
{
    // it's okay to call
}
```

Alternately, you can look into using [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) to reduce some of the confusion involved in working with time zones.